# Ignore all files and folders within a committed folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have the following folder structure:

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> > -- d
> >
> > > -- e
> >
> > -- f

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are folders and the rest are files. The folder `c` is checked into the repository. Now, I want everything under it to be ignored (all files and subfolders).

I tried  `svn propset svn:global-ignores c .` However, `svn status` still shows contents of `c` as non-versioned.

Also tried `svn propset svn:ignore "*" c` and that did not help either.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was by deleting `c` from the repository and then using `svn propset svn:global-ignores c .` Figured there was no point keeping an empty directory in the repository. However, the build process had to ensure this directory is created at build time as it was needed further downstream.